# Using node's path.resolve on Windows

Tags: node.js, path

I'm on node 0.10.X and I don't have access to a Windows machine.

re: https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

When I do:

```
p = path.resolve(someAbsolutePath).replace(/\\/g, '/');
```

Do I expect `p` to start with `c:/` or `/`?

Thanks

Comment: I think it should be `c:/`, absolute means from the start imho

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to write data to a file in Node JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736581/not-able-to-write-data-to-a-file-in-node-js)

Answer (score 13):

Solution that works for linux and windows, without extra conditions:

```
path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'src', 'index.html')
```

will be changed to:

`'../src/index.html'` on linux

`'..\src\index.html'` on windows

Comment: This is the better solution because I want my app to work on either OS

Comment: And, this is much easier to do programmatically using `path.resolve(...pathSegmentArray)`.

Answer (score 6):

On Windows, absolute paths begin with a drive letter, followed by a colon, followed by a backslash (in the form `C:\`).

With this line

```
p = path.resolve(someAbsolutePath).replace(/\\/g, '/');
```

you should expect a path in that format, with the backslash replaced by a forward slash. So if `someAbsolutePath` is on drive C, `p` should start with `C:/`, if it's on drive D, `p` should start with `D:/`, etc.

Comment: I should know for sure tomorrow. If you're right, I'll accept.